# Can I delete .git folder in a completed WP project?

Tags: backup

I manage a WP-based site with a custom theme built by a developer to whom I no longer have access. I am currently backing up the WP files via FTP and am curious about the presence of .git files in our theme folder. There are hundreds of sub-folders containing dozens of files each. Can anyone advise me if it is necessary to maintain that .git folder or is that purely a development tool?

Comment: The `.git` folder contains the information that [`git`](https://git-scm.com/docs/) uses to keep a record of changes to the project. If you're never going to want a record of changes, you can delete the subfolder; conversely, if you ever want access to that record, you'll want to keep the subfolder.

Comment: Thank you, Pat!

Comment: If you have git installed, you can run “git repack -adk” and it’ll pack up most of the subfolders into a single pack file.

Comment: That said, whether the .git folder should be there or not though, if you’re going to do any amount of development you should learn and use git - version control is really useful.

Comment: I don't like leaving .git folders and files on live sites, so I delete them after I've uploaded custom themes or plugins, but leave them in place on my local copies.  Then if I ever make simple changes to the files that are already on the server, I just download the contents of the main plugin folder to my local version (replacing anything that's there) and then I push my changes to github.

Comment: At this point I do not intend to do any development myself -- so I don't see myself utilizing git. Sounds like good advice though to leave it in place in my local folders -- you never know what the future holds and they may be useful to a future developer (or even future-me!) Thanks Rup and Tony!